# Button with label included can cause double firing

Tags: html, jquery, dom-events

I have the problem with labels within buttons because a click on the label is also causing the button click to fire.

So I got two fired events after each other, what I don't want of course.

My buttons with label included look like this:

```
<button id="b" name="Button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    <label id="b_button_label" class="fontf">
        Click me
    </label>
</button>
```

Is there any quick solution, perhaps with jQuery, to prevent the double firing?

Comment: Why use a label? If you want to style parts of the button content separately you could use a span...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, solution is not to put labels *inside* your buttons.

The labels are meant to describe the control itself, and clicks on a control's label will act like a click on the control itself.

From the spec:

> The label represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using for attribute, or by putting **the form control inside the label element** itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a valid HTML code. You cannot add a LABEL inside a BUTTON. A simple way of adding text to your button is:

`<button id="b" name="Button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">click me</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation event in jQuery from bubbling up the event

```
$(function() {
    $('#b_button_label').on('click' , function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();

       // Your code goes here
    });
});​
```

Also why do you want to add the Label inside the button when you have the value field to display its text.

Comment: +1, though the HTML is invalid it does answer how to prevent the click event to reach the button. Off course using valid HTML to being with is always better.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - why is the HTML invalid? `<button>` elements can definitely contain other elements, but I couldn't find a definitive list of exactly which elements are allowed (the w3 examples are `<img>` and `<em>`).

Comment: @nnnnnn: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input, I copied the code and it fails. By default it uses HTML 4.01 strict. The reason it gives is: `document type does not allow element "LABEL" here` and when using XHTML 1.0 strict it says: `document type does not allow element "label" here; missing one of "object", "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "ins", "del", "span", "bdo", "tt", "i", "b", "big", "small", "em", "strong", "dfn", "code", "q", "samp", "kbd", "var", "cite", "abbr", "acronym", "sub", "sup" start-tag`

Comment: Cool, thanks @FrançoisWahl - I guess that is the list of what _is_ allowed inside a `<button>`, except I don't see "img" in the list and you can definitely put an `<img>` in a `<button>` (according to the [w3's example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)).

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think so. When I tried using random elements from that list inside the button it came back as valid HTML. I don't know valid HTML of the top of my head, that is why I usually end up using that site. Regarding the `img` tag, I just run the validator on that and it found it valid in HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0. So the list must be incomplete.

Comment: It's defacto-valid because browsers support it, even the mobile ones.